# Is it possible to add a first and latest posts link?

Tags: posts, links

I'm using the following code to show one post in a page (Blog pages show at most is set to 1 post):

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Front Page
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Prominent
 * @since Prominent 1.0
 */
get_header(); ?>
<div id="tagline">
    <div class="container">
    </div><!-- .container -->
</div><!-- #tagline -->
<div id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="mainbar">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="content-block-2">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php /* Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable */ ?>
            <?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
                <?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; Older posts', 'twentyten' ) ); ?>
                <?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts &rarr;', 'twentyten' ) ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- #mainbar -->
    </div><!-- .container -->
</div><!-- #content-bottom -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

So now I got a prev and next link in my front page. I would like to know if is possible to add a first and latest posts link?

**EDIT:**

By First and Latest posts I mean, for instance,

Since I only allow one post per page, only one post will be shown.

I would like a link for post number 1 and 8 in the example below:

**1** 2 3 4 5 6 7 **8**

Comment: Define `first` and `latest` posts links? What exactly would these be a link to?

Comment: @t31os OK please see my **EDIT**

Comment: The code you've posted is a page template, with no custom query parameters, there's only ever going to be a single result, the page the template is attached to.

Answer (score 2):

What you need are `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages` and [`get_pagenum_link()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_pagenum_link/). Then you just have to compare `get_query_var( 'paged' )` with `max_num_pages` and create a link if they are not equal:

```
/**
 * Link to last page of a paged archive.
 *
 * @param  string $text Link text
 * @return string Nothing if we are on the last page, a link otherwise.
 */
function t5_get_last_posts_link( $text = 'Last Posts' )
{
    global $wp_query;

    if ( // something is very wrong
        ! isset ( $wp_query->max_num_pages )
        // there is just one page
        or 1 == $last = $wp_query->max_num_pages
        // we are already on the last page
        or get_query_var( 'paged' ) == $last
    )
    {
        return '';
    }

    return sprintf( '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>', get_pagenum_link( $last ), $text );
}

/**
 * Link to the first page of a paged archive.
 *
 * @param  string $text Link text
 * @return string Nothing if we are on the first page, a link otherwise.
 */
function t5_get_first_posts_link( $text = 'First Posts' )
{
    global $wp_query;

    if ( // something is very wrong
        ! isset ( $wp_query->max_num_pages )
        // there is just one page
        or 1 == $wp_query->max_num_pages
        // we are already on the first page
        or 2 > (int) get_query_var( 'paged' )
    )
    {
        return '';
    }

    return sprintf( '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>', get_pagenum_link( 1 ), $text );
}
```

### Usage

```
print t5_get_first_posts_link( 'Newest' );
print t5_get_last_posts_link( 'Oldest' );
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears like what you need is "pagination". Install **[WP-PageNavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/)** plugin, and add this in your template file (index.php, archive.php, etc. — whichever is relevant):

```
<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
```

The plugin's settings are self-explanatory. (HINT! `%PAGE_NUMBER%`)